# Jquery delete button is selecting all image srcs and ids (Multiple Upload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a delete button for the ImageUploader.
I don't have any problems with selecting the image and put it inside the div element of my page, it's all about deleting the current image.

When i do click on my delete button it's giving my all the id's and src's and not the selected current one with my delete button. look at my delete button pls where i do console log the src and the id. It's giving my all the id's and src's and i do want the id and src from the current one.

Does someone has a solution?

**This is the select piece which works perfect.**

```
    frame.on( 'select', function() {
        // Get media attachments details from the frame state
        selections = frame.state().get('selection');
        selections.map(function(attachment){
            attachment = attachment.toJSON();

            // Send the attachment URL to our custom image input field
            imgContainer.append(
              '<li>'    
            + '<img data-attachment-id="id-media-1993'+attachment.id+'" src="'+attachment.url+'" class="gallery-thumbnail" alt="'+attachment.title+'" style="max-width:150px; max-height:150px;"/>'
            + '<a class="delete-custom-img" href="#">Remove Image</a>'
            + '</li>');
            // Send the attachment id to our hidden input
            imgIdInput.val(attachment.id);

            console.log(attachment);
        });
    });

    // Finally, open the modal on click
    frame.open();

});
```

**This my delete button**

```
imgContainer.on( 'click', delImgLink, function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var galleryThumbnail = $('.gallery-thumbnail');
    var galleryThumbnailID = $('.gallery-thumbnail').data('attachment-id');         
    var galleryThumbnailSrc = $('.gallery-thumbnail').attr('src');

    $(galleryThumbnail).each(function(){
        var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        console.log(imgSrc);
    });

    $(galleryThumbnail).each(function(){
        var imgIDs = $(this).data("attachment-id");
        console.log(imgIDs);
    });

});
```

[output image id in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un8k1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can select parent element from the button and from there look for the things you want to find.

something like this

```
var img = $(this).closest('li').find('.gallery-thumbnail');
var galleryThumbnail = img;
var galleryThumbnailID = img.data('attachment-id');         
var galleryThumbnailSrc = img.attr('src');
```

Comment: It's still giving my the same output as id. i did put an link inside the code above. inside my html they are both different the attachment id's but when i try to console log it. it's giving my the id of one image for both images. and it's calling both images ass wel when i click only for one image.

Answer (score 0):

At first I think it would be less confusing to add the event handler like this:

```
$('.delete-custom-img').click(function() {...});
```

or

```
$('.delete-custom-img', imgContainer).click(function() {...});
```

if there are other elements with this class outside imgContainer that you don't want to add the event handler to.

But that's personal preference I guess, so to your question:
The problem is that you get all occurrences of '.gallery-thumbnail' on the page because you don't specify any scope for jQuery to look in (like with the imgContainer above).
So you're in the scope of the delete button when clicking on it. In your generated markup it shares the same parent with the thumbnail so you could do something like this:

```
var galleryThumbnail = $('.gallery-thumbnail', $(this).parent());
```

The second argument specifies the scope for jQuery to search for elements with the '.gallery-thumbnail' class in.

Haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure this should solve your problem.